# How to cite simple definitions when writing university papers?

Tags: citations, wikipedia

When writing any kind of paper or homework at the university I am supposed to give references for my citations. At the same time, sources like Wikipedia are not considered good for university level. Now let's say I am writing about malware, and I want to give definition about virus. Wikipedia has a good explanation, but I obviously cannot just copy without references (right?), and to give reference to Wikipedia is considered unacceptable.

So how am I supposed to give reference to such an item? Am I supposed to change the sentence in such a way that it cannot be tracked where I took it from?

Comment: *[...] to give reference to Wikipedia is considered unacceptable.* Why?!

Comment: For university level it is, because it's considered not reliable source, as regular users can edit articles.

Comment: Another nice example how ivory tower rules like "no wiki" makes no sense. Why don't we try Encyclopedia Britannica? ;) But seriously: even for proper academic notions, it is hard to find proper references. I would recommend to properly rephrase it, and google "malware definition": there are cisco, MS, merriam-webster etc   links, they say all the same, pick which is accepted by your prof.

Comment: as for the wikipedia issue, there is a whole question about it http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19083/are-there-instances-where-citing-wikipedia-is-allowed

Comment: @Greg I also think that if the OP thinks wikis are not reliable, why doesn't he refer to more reliable encyclopedias and dictionaries?

Comment: If the wikipedia article offers a citation for what you want to use, go to the original source to double-check the information and then cite the original publication.

Comment: If your only source for something is Wikipedia, you **must** cite Wikipedia.  If your instructor tell that citing Wikipedia is unacceptable, what they really mean is that **using Wikipedia as your only source** is unacceptable.  You're supposed to read and cite primary sources, which Wikipedia is not.  (Neither is _Encyclopedia Britannica_, @Greg.)

Comment: This seems to be an undergrad issue, which is off-topic, here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standards for papers and homework is not the same as for publications. Moreover, there is nothing fundamentally right or wrong about a definition as long as you introduce it as such ! (in University words mean what you decide they mean -- within reason, that is). You can definitely write something like

> In this paper I will use the definition of a *virus* as a '...' (1)

and refer to a footnote that says

> (1) definition taken from Wikipedia article *Virus*, retrieved on
>   2014-10-04".

Of course if Wikipedia's definition is taken from a printed reference, use the latter.

If you want to be extra-cautious you can have a look at the change log and discussion of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: _Of course if Wikipedia's definition is taken from a printed reference, use the latter._ — Only after reading the printed reference yourself, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Two points to remember:

1) Always give a reference for anything which is not your own! Changing the sentence in such a way that it cannot be tracked is NOT an acceptable substitute.

2) For as long as you are a student, the university sets the rules for what is considered an acceptable source.

Since your university, like many others which I am familiar, does not consider Wikipedia to be an acceptable academic resource, you should not cite Wikipedia in papers/homework. (When writing for an audience other than your professor(s), you be the judge. [This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19083/7921) provides a nice overview of the pros and cons of citing Wikipedia.) **For the example you've given, the relevant Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus) has many linked references. The usual workaround is to follow those references, find one which contains the definition you need, and cite that reference rather than Wikipedia.** Of course, as JeffE noted, be sure you've actually read the source you are citing!

Comment: That is not a "workaround"; it is precisely how it is meant to work, even if your university does not explicitly say that, and is why those references exist. If you follow a reference and it matches Wikipedia, cite that; if you cannot find a citation that matches Wikipedia, then you are just reading text by an anonymous stranger, and shouldn't cite it at all.