# How to cite a section of a wikipedia article?

Tags: publications, citations

I'm kinda new to academia and was wondering how citations are done. In particular, say I wanted to cite the "Inspiration, pure and applied mathematics, and aesthetics" of this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics

Would I cite the whole article, or is there a way of citing just the part I want?

Also, who do I mention as the author of a Wikipedia article?

Lastly, what format would is commonly used for writing such a reference?

Comment: In academia, Wikipedia is often not considered a good source to cite, but you should look for primary materials.  For a discussion, see: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19083/19607

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is very basic and broad in scope; have you made any effort to research it? If you search for "citation reference style" on one of the major search engines, the first few pages are full of useful tutorials.

There are many different formats used for references (e.g., Harvard, APA, Vancouver). If this is for an assignment, ask your instructor which format he or she wants you to use. If this is for a journal article you hope to publish, consult the journal submission guidelines.

Normally, page numbers are not required for short articles. For something longer, such as a book, page numbers (or perhaps chapter numbers or section numbers would be used.

Comment: As I said in my answer, a quick google search will turn up loads of tutorials on how to cite all kinds of resources. Once you have determined the format you're using (e.g., Harvard), then pick one of those tutorials and read it. Also, on Wikipedia articles have a "Cite this page" link which will tell you how to cite it in a variety of formats.

Answer (score 1):

Use an APA citation generator. Dont write citations one by one. Even Microsoft Word has a 'references' section where you pasta the data of the site/book/article and its automatically generated. You can use Zotero too (it's a reference manager.)