# Is it possible to use Reddit as a source?

Tags: citations, online-resource

For a writing assignment, I'm doing some research on my topic (CalgaryNEXT). Most sites I've seen report generally the same ideas and the same stats. Then I found [this post of someone who attended a presentation by the project's lead](https://www.reddit.com/r/Calgary/comments/3hl61c/i_attended_the_calgarynext_presentation_and_heres/), and he mentions a few other points not covered elsewhere.

Unfortunately though, its just "some dude on Reddit".

Is there any legitimate way of sourcing something like this, or must I rely on cut-and-paste articles from more reputable news sites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there instances where citing Wikipedia is allowed?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19083/are-there-instances-where-citing-wikipedia-is-allowed)

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I don't know if this is really a duplicate. This is a lot less reliable of a source as Wikipedia; it may have different answers reflecting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would shy away from using reddit.com specifically, as the website has even less clout than Wikipedia (which at least attempts to source their material). If the author was a reporter, his job is on the line for being factual. On reddit, there are no repercussions for posting mistakes. Unfortunately, you might have to rely on newspaper articles for this one.

Comment: I like this answer.  One more idea, @Carcigenicate -- if you could get in touch with the person who posted at Reddit, and ask permission to use his name, then I suppose you could cite a Personal Communication.