# Where to put the citation for a review article

Tags: citations

I'm writing an article about a topic and I found a review with a block of citations that is really interesting.

If I use the same sources in the same sequence (after paraphrasing with my own words), where should I cite the review? Do I put the citation at the acknowledgement or after the used resources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to incorporate a block of citations from a review paper into my own paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42440/is-it-okay-to-incorporate-a-block-of-citations-from-a-review-paper-into-my-own-p)

Comment: i read it but couldn't comment there , but my question is how to cite the review?? after the used resources in the literature review or at the acknowledgement ?

Comment: Per these comments, I have edited to focus on the location aspect of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, citations should be placed at the point where you actually use the information, not in acknowledgements.

For a case like this, then, you might say something like:

> A useful review of this area may be found in [citation], which suggests viewing the field as follows: [paraphrased review material].

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification